# Can a plane help a second aircraft with landing gear issue mid-air?

Tags: pilot-technique, wwii

My Father received his flight training in the Navy in 1941. He flew mostly [Curtiss Wright SNC's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss-Wright_CW-22) (a model of the CW-22) and [Grumman F3F's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F3F). The story I was told is hard to believe, so I'm hoping that some of you pilots out there (I'm not one) can tell me if this kind of stuff really happened.

While returning from a training run and preparing to land in an SNC, one landing gear would not go down. A second plane pulled alongside my Father's plane and with its wing tried to knock the landing gear loose! While in mid-air!

I find this hard to believe, but hey, you never know.

Many thanks for any insights!

td

Comment: There is a true tale of an F-86 pilot in Korea that kept a mate in the air after an engine failure from flak damage by nosing up to his tail pipe and pushing him along for some number of minutes, long enough to get the guy out over the sea where the Navy could rescue him.  The guy punched out and landed in the water, but drowned from getting entangled in the parachute lines as the rescue helicopter approached.

Comment: It's plausible, I don't know of any documented cases of it being done.

Comment: You’ve seen [this video](https://youtu.be/T-_eEYamuNw)?